# Stopping time - Stochastic Processes

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Suppose I have a sequence of random variables $X_{1} ... X_{n}$ such that $X_{i}$ takes a random value from the set ${-1,0,1}$ with equal probability. Now take the sum of the sequence $X_{1} ... X_{n}$ and call this $S$.

Now, let u,v be integers with u > 0 and v < 0

$J = min \{n:S \leq v$ or $S \geq u\}$

My question is how do I interpret what J is? Is it basically the minimum $n$ such that the sum of the sequence is either less than v or greater than u? In other words, the first n that exceeds one of these bounds? If so, how does J relate to a [stopping time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time)?

My thinking is the J is definitely a stopping time since we can determine at each n whether or not the sum of the sequence has exceeded either u or v.

Comment: Yes $J=\inf\{n\geqslant1\mid S_n\geqslant u\ \text{or}\ S_n\leqslant v\}$ and yes $J$ is a stopping time because, for every $n$, the event $[J\leqslant n]=\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n[S_k\geqslant u]\cup[S_k\leqslant v]$ is in the sigma-algebra $\sigma(S_1,\ldots,S_n)=\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest to visualize what $J$ is if you just plot a trajectory of the sequence $X_i$ or $S_i$ respectively. Suppose that the horizontal axis is your timeframe with the discrete values $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the vertical axis is $S_n(\omega)$ for a fixed realization $\omega$. If you now draw horizontal lines $y = u$ and $y = v$, $n$ gives you the passing time through either line. So if you have a sequence of realizations such that $S_m(\omega) \ge v$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $u < S_n(\omega) < v$ for all prior times $n \le m$, then $J(\omega)$ will be $m$. So it is a random number itself, giving you the first time that the graph $n \mapsto S_n(\omega)$ goes below/above $u$ or $v$ (whatever the bigger number is).

As you can see from Did's comment, it is indeed a stopping time, which is intuitive, since $J(\omega) \le n$ only depends on the realizations of the first $n$ variables, the more formal argument being Did's decomposition of the event $\{ J \le n \}$.

Let me give another comment on BruceETs answer: I would not go as far as to say this is offtopic, but based on your question I suppose it lacks a little transition. Since your sequence $(S_n)_n$ is a martingale (by the independence property), one should know that martingale theory was mostly derived from gambling problems such as the ruin problem explained by BruceET. However, you can imagine $(S_n)_n$ also describing any other discrete stochastic process, for example the number of some population, which can either increase, decrease or remain constant over time with equal probability.